# Product -> Content -> Edit with Page Builder -> Apply Template -> CMS Block application problem

Tags: cms-block, page-builder

When inserting the previously created CMS block into product description,      i can apply template in pagebuilder in Super Admin, but i cannot apply template if i am not Super Admin.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks for letting us know.

The Magento ver. 2.3.5-p2.

[image]

Comment: which locale is set in your magento? like en_US

Answer (score 0):

Please run below command with your language pack/locale like en_AU whatever you configured and also add en_US must.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US en_AU -f
```

I think different locale selected  for both admin user in admin.

hope this helps you

Comment: The solution to the problem was patched in Magento ver: 2.3.5-p2 and it worked fine.
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: happy to hear you fixed it :)